# Having an issue with time.sleep in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, time, sleep

I'm running this very simple function for testing:

```
import time
def printnum(ang):
    if ang > 0:
        print(ang)
        time.sleep(3 * abs(ang) / 360)
        print("done")
    if ang < 0:
        print(ang)
        time.sleep(3 * abs(ang) / 360)
        print("done")
```

When I run it on python 3 it works fine
However, on python 2 I get an issue where `printnum` doesn't work on a wide range of numbers, it doesn't perform the delay... In fact, so far it has only worked with `printnum(180)` in my tests.

This is weird for a code that is so simple. I've tested on 2 computers. Does it happen to you? Any reason why? Suggestions to make it work? (Other than moving to python 3 which is hard on the hardware I'm working with)

Comment: integer division makes `3 * abs(ang) / 360` zero. try `3.0 * abs(ang) / 360`

Comment: Python 2 `/` does *integer division* between two `int` objects. To get the true-division behavior, `from __future__ import division`

Answer (score 1):

On Python 2, `/` defaults to truncating integer division when passed `int` operands, not "true division" (which produces `float` results). You can fix in one of two ways:

1. Add `from __future__ import division` to the top of the file to use Python 3 division rules (`/` means true division always, where you use `//` if you really mean floor division)
2. Change either `3` or `360` to `float` literals so the math is performed `float`-style, e.g. `time.sleep(3. * abs(ang) / 360)` or `time.sleep(3 * abs(ang) / 360.)`

Answer (score 1):

since `ang` is probably an integer small enough then `3 * abs(ang) / 360` is an expression where one integer divides another.

Python 2 division is integer division by default so the result is probably 0.

Fix:

```
3.0 * abs(ang) / 360
```